# Comparing the difference in mean responses (groups 1 and 2 vs. groups 3 and 4; no group has any of same people or same number of people in it)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mean

Study participants read one out of four possible story versions, then responded by rating something on an 11-point scale. I want to compare the difference between responses for those who read story Version 1 vs. those who read story Version 2, on the one hand, VERSUS the difference between responses for those who read story Version 3 and story Version 4 on the other hand. Each study participant only read one of the four story versions. There were approximately 1000 study participants, but a sightly different number of participants read each version (i.e., it was NOT precisely 250 per version).

The claim I'm hoping to test is something like: "The difference in mean ratings in response to Version 3 and 4, on the one hand, is significantly greater than the difference in mean ratings in response to Versions 1 and 2."

What statistical test would I use?